# Long time execution of simple SQL script

Tags: google-bigquery, bq

When I run below script, the query runs about for 30 seconds but when it finishes then I can get information that elapsed time is equal to 0.1 seconds and compute time is 2ms.

Could you tell me what is the reason why this query is running 30 seconds even though I do not use any table?

```
declare heads bool;
declare heads_in_a_row int64 default 0; #number of heads in a row
declare nb_of_throws int64 default 0; #number of throws


#How many throws I need to get a 8 heads in a row?

while heads_in_a_row <= 8 DO

  set heads = RAND() < 0.5;
  set nb_of_throws = nb_of_throws +1;

    if heads then
      set heads_in_a_row = heads_in_a_row + 1 ;
    else
      set heads_in_a_row = 0;
    end if;

end while;

select nb_of_throws;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will sometimes be fast and sometimes be slow, it depends on random chance to get to the point of having 8 heads in a row. Try 50 heads in a row, you'll see its much slower, 2 heads in a row will be faster. The 0.1s elapsed time you are seeing is the elapsed time only for the final section of the script which is the `select` statement which just pulls your stored variable value and is nearly instant.

Answer (score 0):

What is your answer?  I have run it a few times and got results in the hundreds and thousands of 'throws'.  The odds of getting 8 heads in a row is .39%, so not very likely.  BQ (and databases in general) are optimized for set-based and column-based computation, not loop-based operations.  Using BQ for this problem is likely not your best option, python would be much faster for example.